# JavaScript's *this* keyword points to the window from within string.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

Okay, this will probably earn me the Headslam of the Day badge.

Why is `this` pointing at `window` in the following code?

```
if (!String.prototype.Trim)
{
    String.prototype.Trim = function()
    {
        var result = this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        return result;
    };
}
```

As I understand it, `this` should evaluate to the value of the current string instance. Instead, it's evaluating to the current window object. Thus, the following fails miserably:

```
var baz = 'foo bar      '.Trim();
```

Note that this code has been used for quite some time, and is based on code I see advertised all over the place on the intartoobs. So this pattern seems to be the recommended way of doing this. I can't figure out why `this` isn't pointing to the data I think it should be pointing at. (In Visual Studio, when I hover over it, or view it in the Watches window, it shows up as `[object window]`).

(IE 8 [32-bit]; Win7; plain-ole HTML page.)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (even in IE6).  Can you post some more context?

Comment: Yep...It works fine for me. Check http://jsfiddle.net/vTct9/1/

Comment: Did you actually try it on the browser or is this only from within VS?

Comment: How are you testing/debugging this code? I am looking into this and think that the problem has to do with the execution context of the Trim function (or possibly the "var baz = ..." function).  The window object is the global object in IE, and I suspect that your function is being executed in the global context and that is causing "this" to resolve to "window"...

Comment: I am executing this in Visual STudio. I'll reset the project to launch from IE to verify that it's not WebDev causing the issue. Also, there are other prototype functions involved. I'm going to eliminate all the others and add them back one by one to see if one of them is causing the issue. I'll get back to you guys with my results! Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Visual Studio, when I hover over
>   it, or view it in the Watches window,
>   it shows up as [object window]

Sounds like a scope resolution bug in VS. There's no way this can be a bug in IE or else thousands of prototypal functions would break.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently and found the cause was the JS bundler mangling my code. I was able to fix it by enclosing code modifying `String.prototype` in an anonymous function and then calling it.

So instead of:

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function () { ... }
```

I had to write:

```
(function () {
    String.prototype.myFunction = function () {
        ...
    }
})();
```

Comment: It also happened to me when I "bundle" or "pack" one of my Javascript code to reduce its size.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when the parentheses after function name were missing, for example

**Error**

```
'My String'.myFunction
```

**Fix**

```
'My String'.myFunction()
```